# Role based Auth not working with Cookie based Authentication being developed using JWT Auth

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have a JWT token being returned from the API to my client app here's my JWT code:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
                             {
                                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email.ToString()),
                                    new Claim(ApplicationConstants.UserId, applicationUser.Id.ToString()),
                             };

                if (applicationUser.FirstName != null)
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ApplicationConstants.FirstName, applicationUser.FirstName));
                }
                if (applicationUser.NormalizedUserName != null)
                {
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ApplicationConstants.UserName, applicationUser.NormalizedUserName));
                }

                //only if the user is vendor
                if (vendorUser != null) {
                    claims.Add(new Claim(RoleNameConstants.Vendor, vendorUser.Id.ToString()));
                    claims.Add(new Claim(ApplicationConstants.VendorId, vendorUser.VendorId.ToString()));
                }

                var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

                //Adding UserClaims to JWT claims
                foreach (var item in userRoles)
                {
                    //claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ApplicationConstants.Roles, item));
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item));
                }

                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_jwtSettings.Secret);

                #region code smell - don't look
                //var claims = new List<Claim>
                //{
                //    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
                //    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                //    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
                //    new Claim("id", user.Id)
                //};

                //var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
                //claims.AddRange(userClaims);

                //var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                //foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
                //{
                //    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));

                //    var role = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(userRole);
                //    if (role == null) continue;
                //    var roleClaims = await _roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(role);

                //    foreach (var roleClaim in roleClaims)
                //    {
                //        if (claims.Contains(roleClaim))
                //            continue;

                //        claims.Add(roleClaim);
                //    }
                //}
                #endregion

                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claimsIdentity),
                    //Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(_jwtSettings.TokenLifetime),
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30),
                    SigningCredentials =
                    new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                };

                var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
```

and I am using that to build my cookies based authentication in the ASP.NET Identity like this:

```
var stream = response.Token;
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(stream);
            var token = handler.ReadToken(stream) as JwtSecurityToken;

            //my code
            var claims = new List<Claim>();

            foreach (var tokenClaim in token.Claims)
            {
                var claim = new Claim(tokenClaim.Type, tokenClaim.Value);
                claims.Add(claim);
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);

            //var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, nameType, roleType);

            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                AllowRefresh = true,
                IsPersistent = userRequest == null ? false : userRequest.RememberMe,
                ExpiresUtc = token.ValidTo,
                IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
            };

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                principal,
                authProperties);

            _httpContextAccessor.AddCookie("token", response.Token, token.ValidTo);  
            //_sessionManager.SetString("token", response.Token);

            HttpContext.User = principal;
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User = principal;
```

now this code works correctly to Authenticate the user but this doesn't work correctly for authorization for roles when I use `[Authorize(Roles = "Vendor,VendorAdmin")]` attributes, it doesn't let the user pass even if he has those roles.

Here's my code in startup:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {

                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }/*CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme*/) // Sets the default scheme    to cookies
           .AddCookie(options =>
           {
               options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
               options.AccessDeniedPath = "/home/error";
           });
```

Comment: what does this.User() ? return in code...is it authorized ?

Comment: @RohitKumar if I do `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` it shows me true inside my controller action and also has claims for roles.

Comment: have you debugged to see the list of claims of the authenticated user? it should contain the role info. Otherwise there must be something wrong which is not on the asp.net core framework side.

Comment: @Hopeless yes it contains the role claims in the `user.identity.claims`

Comment: You are using ClaimType.Role which contains "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", try using the claim "role" instead.

Comment: @ThomasErdösi I am using the same

Answer (score 1):

I tested your scenario. The key of the role in the claim obtained from the API is a string `role`.

[image]

But `Roles` in `[Authorize(Roles = "Vendor,VendorAdmin")]` need the key `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`.

Then re-add role in cookie based authentication project.

```
        foreach (var tokenClaim in token.Claims)
        {
            if (tokenClaim.Type == "role")
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, tokenClaim.Value));
                continue;
            }
            var claim = new Claim(tokenClaim.Type, tokenClaim.Value);
            claims.Add(claim);
        }
```

[image]

Then it can access the authorized method.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Vendor")]
    public IActionResult Resource()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

Comment: @Zeeshan Adil, can you accept this answer, or have any other issues?